# Using Prototype scope to create DataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a Prototyped Scoped Spring bean using the given configuration. The details for url, username, password, driver will be determined at runtime. Here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
class Cfg {
    @Bean
    public Function<DataSourcePropertiesMap, DriverManagerDataSource> functionOfDriverMgrDS() {
        return this::driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Lazy
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource(DataSourcePropertiesMap dbPropsMap) {
        var ds = new DriverManagerDataSource(dbPropsMap.getDbURL(), dbPropsMap.getDbUsername(), dbPropsMap.getDbPassword());
        ds.setDriverClassName(dbPropsMap.getDbDriver());
        return ds;
    }
}
```

And the DataSourcePropertiesMap is simply a container for the four arguments as below:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DataSourcePropertiesMap {

    @NonNull private final String dbURL;
    @NonNull private final String dbUsername;
    @NonNull private final String dbPassword;
    @NonNull private final String dbDriver;
}
```

Whenever, I boot the application it throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dbHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dbHealthContributor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManagerDataSource' defined in class path resource [Cfg.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'driverManagerDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'DataSourcePropertiesMap' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Why Spring still requires arguments for DriverManagerDataSource with valid driver class for Prototyped Scoped beans. My assumption is it will register a bean someway and create a new instance whenever a call is made with the arguments. If I create a default bean of type `DataSourcePropertiesMap` with dummy values it requires a valid driverclass.

Comment: you can use @Qualifier annotation with naming driverManagerDataSource and call that bean with that name.

Comment: It's about autowiring a bean of type ```DataSourcePropertiesMap ```. But if I've to provide all the details at bootup then I think it defeats the purpose of prototype scope

Answer (score 0):

Editing my original answer since I have not seen this part of the question

> The details for url, username, password, driver will be determined at
> runtime.

As of spring boot 2.x there is still no automatic way of loading properties on runntime. You would have to manually parse the file and read those properties inside this prototype bean method.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. The application will load different properties at runtime and parse the values and create an instance of ```DataSourcePropertiesMap``` and ```Function<DataSourcePropertiesMap, DriverManagerDataSource>``` will give a new instance. But why do I have to ```@Autowire``` one default instance of  ```DataSourcePropertiesMap``` in config in order to start the app?

Comment: @Mohammad I have edited my answer, you can't do that with automatic help from Spring as you try to do. You need to manually read and parse the file and load those configurations in your method